# Allow text to reflow in terminal mode after resizing

Tags: vim-windows, terminal-buffer

I opened up a terminal with `:terminal`. Then I ran a server process that prints logs whenever someone hits the API. Next, I resized gnome-terminal, but I noticed vim didn't update the view of the server logs.

Is there a way to allow the vim `:terminal` to redraw or reflow the text whenever the gnome-terminal window resizes?

This is what `termwinsize` is set to. Not sure if that's the right setting for this.

```
:set termwinsize?
termwinsize=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When text is output by a program, that’s the output—fin.

To reflow a program’s output would require

1. Regenerating it; or
2. Piping it to a formatting program; or
3. Copying it into an editor that can reflow.

Once it’s on the screen, you won’t have much luck changing how it displays.